# What does "MX" mean in the job title "Staff Software Engineer - FE Full Stack MX"?

Tags: job-description

I've been googling about 10 minutes now and can't figure this out. What is the "MX"? What's it mean?

Example job description: [careers.walmart.com: "(USA) Staff Software Engineer - FE Full Stack MX"](https://careers.walmart.com/us/jobs/WD649984-usa-staff-software-engineer-fe-full-stack-mx)

Check my understanding:

- FE = Front End (user-facing software, GUIs, graphics, webpages, etc.)
- BE = Back End (databases, servers, etc.)
- MX = ? (all I can think is "maintenance")

Note: a detailed description of duties is better than a one or two word response.

Update: here's another one: ["Technical Lead Software Engineer, Performance - MX"](https://jobs.cisco.com/jobs/ProjectDetail/Technical-Lead-Software-Engineer-Performance-MX/1364532), from Cisco Meraki (they do routers and networking).

Comment: MX security platform?

Comment: Given that the position is with their International Digital Experiences team and they are looking for experience in UX (User Experience), I'm not convinced this isn't a typo.

Comment: The only other job posting I found with "MX" in it that wasn't for either a company/product/service/team with "MX" in the name or a position located in Mexico was something for Cisco Meraki. It also didn't explain what MX means but it was a job working with embedded systems and bears no resemblance to the work described in the Walmart posting. (OK, that's apparently related to the thing Kilisi mentioned.)

Comment: @BSMP, yes, I've also seen Cisco Meraki job descriptions with "MX" in the job title.

Comment: @BSMP, I updated the question with a link to a Cisco Meraki job with "MX" in its title.

Comment: I actually think, given that its walmart, it means Merchant eXperience.  That's a common term inside ecommerce.

Answer (score 8):

The best thing to do would be to contact Walmart's human resources department and **ask** for clarification.  We didn't write the job posting, so anything you read here is pure speculation.

Per a Google search: "You can contact Walmart HR at 866-368-3289 for questions and concerns regarding job applications, work issues, employee benefits, and more."

Answer (score 4):

The 'MX' in your first link for Walmart job ad and the 'MX' in the second link about Cisco are two different things.

The Walmart MX is

> walmart.com.mx, operated by Nueva Walmart de México, S. de R.L. de C.V., is an online store with nationally-focused sales.

Please see https://ecommercedb.com/en/store/walmart.com.mx

The second 'MX" is Security Appliances (MX) which is associated with Cisco Meraki

Please see https://meraki.cisco.com/lib/pdf/meraki_datasheet_mx.pdf

Comment: You've conflated a url that ends in "[dash]mx" as part of the path with a host name that ends in "[dot]mx".  The latter is a top level domain for Mexico, but page shown for the link says the job posting is in Sunnyvale (California).  Sorry. Great big nope.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that it is a simple typo, that they had intended to write **UX**. However this makes for a strange job description, focusing on FE (Front End), Full Stack and UX (User Experience), *UX* in this case being synonymous with *FE*... IMO the role is either Full stack, or something specific, this might just be a brazen grab for keywords.

Other job adds on Upwork and Linked In, like the one you have listed that use **MX**, commonly refer to the [MX Linux OS](https://mxlinux.org/).

- [Technical Lead Software Engineer, Performance - MX](https://jobs.cisco.com/jobs/ProjectDetail/Technical-Lead-Software-Engineer-Performance-MX/1364532)
  ... *As a Technical Lead Software Engineer of **MX***

> MX Linux is a midweight Linux operating system based on Debian stable and using core antiX components, with additional software created or packaged by the MX community. MX Linux was developed as a cooperative venture between the antiX and former MEPIS communities. The MX 'name' came from the M for MEPIS and the X from antiX - an acknowledgment of their roots. The community's stated goal is to produce "a family of operating systems that are designed to combine elegant and efficient desktops with high stability and solid performance".

Walmart do use a linux variant for their POS, so it is possible that they are looking for someone fluent in that codebase and that it could be *MX Linux*, though I cannot confirm that, there is also no mention of linux/unix in the description but this reference indicates that there is a potential for something outside of the standard box: *this is a startup-like environment*.

- In many scenarios, if the acronyms used in the job offer are not immediately recognisable to you, especially for *senior* or *engineer* roles, then there is a high chance that your skillset and experience is not sufficient for the role, that doesn't account for poor spelling, but if they can't get the job ad right, its does not bode well for the rest of the workplace experience :P

Comment: While your last bullet point can be true in some cases, it's also often just that someone doesn't realize how parochial their terms are.  My gut feeling is any linux dev would probably be suitable although fans of SystemD probably wouldn't find it appealing.  Beyond that a lot of places write job specs for a dream candidate and then hire someone who's only got a few of the bullet points because they're the closest fitting applicant to interview well.

Answer (score 1):

> What does "MX" mean in the job title...

I can't answer for the [Walmart job](https://careers.walmart.com/us/jobs/WD649984-usa-staff-software-engineer-fe-full-stack-mx) yet, but for the [Meraki job](https://jobs.cisco.com/jobs/ProjectDetail/Technical-Lead-Software-Engineer-Performance-MX/1364532) I asked a recruiter, and here is the recruiter's reply (emphasis added):

> **MX** is abbreviated **'M' for Meraki** and **'X' = intersection of multifunctional security** including SD-WAN appliances, routers, switches, and etc. Hope this helps!

So, "MX" to Meraki therefore means "Meraki's work on security in the domain where routers, switches, network devices, etc, all intersect".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).